# Pattern in carrot's body

Tags: decorating, carrots

Is this rhombus-like pattern in carrot totally random or is it a specific variety? If so, good to know for decorating ideas.

[image: carrot-rhombus]

Answer (score 3):

It is a symptom of unusual growth conditions not variety or anything

Over-watering is the most likely culprit. This resulted in rapid growth. As carrots grow from the center, the formerly small outer parts weren't able to grow rapidly enough to keep up with the middle and resulted in spaces left behind.

Comment: or maybe a sign that the carrot is drying out instead?

Comment: Yup, could be that too.